# Search a 3d Array

Tags: c++, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I need help with inputting a search array. I tried putting a binary search but I can't get it to work. everything else works up until I put the value I am searching for in the array, then it just crashes.

How it suppose to work:
input 2 coordinates with a value each
then it calculates the distance between them
then it suppose to let user search the coordinates for a value and state if found which coordinate it is at.

Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  //for setprecision
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <cstdlib>  // Needed for rand and srand
#include <ctime>    // Needed for the time function


using namespace std;


//Function Prototypes
void processThroughArray(int[][10][10], int, int, int, int, int, int);
int searchArray(int[][10][10], int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
const int SIZE = 10;

int main()
{

// establish array and set all values to 0
int myArray[10][10][10] = { 0 };

// establish x and y position markers
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
int x2 = 0;
int y2 = 0;
int z2 = 0;


// establish input for x and y from the user
int xInput = 0;
int yInput = 0;
int zInput = 0;
int xInput2 = 0;
int yInput2 = 0;
int zInput2 = 0;

// variable for value entered
int inputValue = 0;
int inputValue2 = 0;
double distance = 0;
int searchValue;
int result;


// Get the user's value and coordinate
cout << "\nPlease enter the x coordinate ";
cin >> xInput;
cout << "\nPlease enter the y coordinate ";
cin >> yInput;
cout << "\nPlease enter the z coordinate ";
cin >> zInput;


cout << "\nPlease enter the value to place in " << xInput << "," << yInput << "," << zInput << " ";
cin >> inputValue;

// Get the user's ending value and coordinate
cout << "\nPlease enter the ending x coordinate ";
cin >> xInput2;
cout << "\nPlease enter the ending y coordinate ";
cin >> yInput2;
cout << "\nPlease enter the ending z coordinate ";
cin >> zInput2;


cout << "\nPlease enter the value to place in " << xInput2 << "," << yInput2 << "," << zInput2 << " ";
cin >> inputValue2;

// place the value in the coordinate
myArray[xInput][yInput][zInput] = inputValue;
cout << "\nYou have successfully placed the value " << inputValue << " in coordinate " << xInput << ", " << yInput << ", " << zInput << " ";

myArray[xInput2][yInput2][zInput2] = inputValue2;
cout << "\nYou have successfully placed the value " << inputValue2 << " in coordinate " << xInput2 << ", " << yInput2 << ", " << zInput2 << " ";

//Function performing for loop
processThroughArray(myArray, x, y, z, x2, y2, z2);

//calculate distance between the two coordinates
distance = sqrt(pow(xInput2 - xInput, 2.0) + pow(yInput2 - yInput, 2.0) + pow(zInput2 - zInput, 2.0));
cout << "\nThe distance between " << xInput << "," << yInput << "," << zInput << " and " << xInput2 << "," << yInput2 << "," << zInput2 << " is ";
cout << setprecision(4) << distance << endl;


// indicate end of array processing
cout << "\nArray Processed" << endl;

//User inputs value to search for
cout << "Enter the value you wish to look for: ";
cin >> searchValue;

result = searchArray(myArray, SIZE, searchValue, x, y, z, x2, y2,z2);

//If results contains a -1 the value not found

if (result == -1 )
{
    cout << "That number does not exists in the array.\n";
}

else 
{
    cout << "\nValue " << searchValue;
    cout << " is located at position: " << result << endl;

}




system("pause");
return 0;
}


//**************************************************************************
// Definition of function processThroughArray: Process through the array   *
//the for loop                                                             *
//**************************************************************************
void processThroughArray(int myArray[][10][10], int x, int y, int z, int x2, int y2, int z2)
{

for (int x = 0, x2 = 0; x<10, x2 < 10; x++, x2++)
{
    for (int y = 0, y2 = 0; y<10, y2 < 10; y++, y2++)

    {
        for (int z = 0, z2 = 0; z< 10, z2 < 10; z++, z2++)
        {

            // Display the value of the coordinate
            cout << "\nCordinate " << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << " value is " << myArray[x, x2][y, y2][z, z2];

        }
    }
}



}

//**************************************************************************
// Definition of function searchArray: search array for the value input    *
//                                                                         *
//**************************************************************************
int searchArray(int myArray[][10][10], int size, int value,int x, int y, int z, int x2, int y2, int z2)
{
int index = 0;
int position = -1;
bool found = false;


while (index < size && !found)
{
    if (myArray[index][index][index] == value)
    {
        found = true;
        position = index;

    }
    index++;

} 

return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `SIZE` as 1000, and you're passing it to searchArray():

```
const int SIZE = 1000;

// ...

searchArray(myArray, SIZE, searchValue);
```

You are doing the following in searchArray():

```
int searchArray(int myArray[][10][10], int size, int value)
{
    int first = 0,
        last = size - 1,
```

Since `size` is 1000, you are setting "first" to 0 and "last" to 999.

Then, you're doing the following (leaving out some irrelevant stuff):

```
middle = (first + last) / 2;
if (myArray[middle][middle][middle] = value)
```

So, let's take out a piece of paper, and a pencil. Since "first" is 0, and "last" is 999, this sets "middle" to 449.

So, we have two problems here:

1) You're assigning using the "=" operator, instead of comparing using "==", which appears to be your intent.

2) You are assigning a value to myArray[449][449][449]. Unfortunately, your array is much, much smaller:

```
int myArray[10][10][10] = { 0 };
```

Trying to access the 449th's element of the 449th array of ten elements, of the 449th array of ten arrays of ten elements, is not going to work very well. Even if you were comparing, or assigning something, either way this is undefined behavior, and an almost guaranteed crash.

Comment: Here's an update.

I've worked through the linear search but not quite sure what i'm doing wrong at this point.
The issue i'm currently having is that it isn't searching the array correctly. 
It finds the first number but can't find the second number. 
Also still not able to to put in the coordinates it is found on but i'm sure I need to focus on fixing the first part before moving on to that.

Thanks, Angela

Comment: The new version of the code will check myArray[0][0][0], then myArray[1][1][1], and so on, up until myArray[9][9][9]. It will search only ten elements in your array, and completely ignore the other 990. So, unless you're searching for something that could only be found in those 10 coordinates, you're not going to find it.